# create a morris chart in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

so I was able to build a Morris chart following some tutorials, and this is what I've come up with so far

```
$range = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(30);

$stats = DB::table('tickets')
        ->where('created_at', '>=', $range)
        ->groupBy('date')
        ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
        ->get([
            DB::raw('Date(created_at) as date'),
            DB::raw('COUNT(*) as value')
        ])
        ->toJSON();
```

**OUTPUT**

```
"[{"date":"2018-11-10","value":1},{"date":"2018-11-11","value":1}]"
```

the thing is I'm trying to get the results by months and ticket status not daily.

js code

```
Morris.Area({
            element: 'morris-area-chart'
            , data: data
            , xkey: 'date'
            , ykeys: ['status']
        });
```

**Tickets Table**

```
id|phone_model |cus_name |issue |notes |created_at |updated_at |status
```

**Expected Output**

```
[{"date":"11","tickets":2,"status":1},{"date":"11","tickets":1,"status":2}, 
{"date":"10","tickets":3,"status":1},{"date":"10","tickets":1,"status":3},]
```

I tried more than a way to get the results based on months and ticket status but no luck
any help will be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: If you want to show it by month then you should probably put the month name into your output instead of the whole date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
$result_arr = \DB::select("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%m') date, status, COUNT(*) count FROM tickets GROUP BY date, status ORDER BY date DESC");
return collect($result_arr)->toJson();
```

It outputs such a result for example(Output is in mysql console here):

```js
+------+--------+-------+  
| date | status | count |  
+------+--------+-------+  
| 12   |      1 |     1 |  
| 12   |      2 |     3 |  
| 12   |      4 |     1 |  
| 12   |     10 |     7 |  
| 11   |      1 |     1 |  
| 11   |      2 |     1 |  
| 11   |      4 |     1 |  
| 10   |      1 |     3 |  
| 10   |      2 |     2 |  
| 10   |      3 |     1 |  
| 10   |      4 |     2 |  
| 09   |      1 |     2 |  
| 09   |      2 |     7 |  
| 09   |      3 |     5 |  
| 08   |      1 |     1 |  
| 08   |      2 |     1 |  
| 08   |     12 |     1 |  
| 07   |      1 |     4 |  
| 06   |      1 |     1 |  
| 06   |      2 |    12 |  
| 06   |      3 |     2 |  
| 05   |      1 |     1 |  
| 05   |      2 |     8 |  
| 05   |     11 |     1 |  
| 04   |      1 |     2 |  
| 04   |      2 |     8 |  
| 04   |     10 |     1 |  
| 03   |      1 |     2 |  
| 02   |      1 |     2 |  
| 02   |      2 |    26 |  
| 02   |      3 |     1 |  
| 02   |     11 |     2 |  
| 02   |     12 |     1 |  
| 01   |      2 |    21 |  
| 01   |      3 |     8 |  
| 01   |     10 |     6 |  
+------+--------+-------+  
36 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Keep in mind that as you want to group the results based on both `status & date` it does not give you just a row for each date(as you may have multiple statuses), so for each `date` you may have different values for each `status`.

See [Mysql Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for more about `DATE_FORMAT`.